# Elastic Search weird behavior - some api call do not get invoked

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm using the [python-dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/) client to run a local instance of elastic search.

Some calls do not seem to be working.

Hee's a quick runnable example

```
import time

import elasticsearch_dsl
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

e = Elasticsearch()

q = {"hello": "world"}
for i in range(3):
    e.index("wtf", q)
s: Search = Search(using=e, index="wtf").query("match_all")
for i in s:
    print(i.to_dict())
s: Search = Search(using=e, index="wtf").query("match_all").delete()
```

I expected all document in the index `wtf` to be deleted (since that's the last query). But when I go to http://localhost:9200/wtf/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*,

it shows me three json blobs... presumably because the `delete()` call did not run at all.

HOWEVER:

if I intersperse  a `time.sleep(3)` between the `index() and delete()` calls, I get the expected output: no json blobs

What's going on here?

I'm running the binaries for  `elasticsearch-6.5.0.` locally

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the ES's **near-realtime** property.

https://docs.genesys.com/Documentation/UCS/9.1.x/Admin/Elasticsearch

TLDR: Writing data a disk is expensive, so it  writes to segments. It takes a while for elastic search to update all shards to have the same segment copy, so you have explicitly call the `refresh` endpoint.